# VBA to click object in Internet Explorer

Tags: vba

I would like to click on an object in Internet Explorer using VBA to automatically navigate through a webpage.

```
For Each oHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("a")
    If oHTML_Element.Title = "CSV" Then
        oHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
    End If
Next oHTML_Element
```

This is the code I am trying to use, and have used successfully before in my Excel Macro, but it is not working for this object, and I am not sure why.

This is the HTML code for the object I am trying to click:

```html
<a id="apexir_dl_CSV" href=",DanaInfo=web1.us.industry.somecompany.net,SSL+f?p=103:5:1156695844453492:CSV::::">
 <img title="CSV" alt="CSV" src="/i41/ws/,DanaInfo=web1.us.industry.somecompany.net,SSL+download_csv_64x64.gif">​
```

Comment: It looks like your a tag does not have a title attribute. The Image tag does, but you're not looking for Image tags in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you have shown did you try

```
Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0,0,2) '<== you can adjust the 2 which is number of seconds to wait
HTMLDoc.getElementById("apexir_dl_CSV").Click
```

Or

```
While IE.Busy = True Or IE.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
Dim b As Object
Do: DoEvents: On Error Resume Next: Set b = IE.document.getElementById("apexir_dl_CSV"): On Error GoTo 0: Loop While b Is Nothing    '<== Loops until object found (should include a timeout to prevent infinite looping)
IE.document.getElementById("apexir_dl_CSV").Click
```

Comment: I had not tried this. Trying this code now, I get Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set. However, when I hit debug and then continue running the Macro it then works.

Comment: This works, so I guess the webpage had not fully loaded yet. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Your anchor tag doesn't have a title attribute so you can't find that anchor to click it. Instead find the anchor tag by looking for it by its id attribute.

This is what worked for me.

```
 For Each oHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("a")
    If oHTML_Element.ID = "apexir_dl_CSV" Then
        oHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
    End If
Next oHTML_Element
```

Hope that helps.